# Passive imputation with categorical:continuous interaction in R

Tags: linear-regression, interaction, imputation, r-mice

I am trying to do a passive imputation to deal with a continuous:categorical interaction in a linear regression model (total_sleep ~ mean_commute + sex + mean_commute:sex)

I have used the solution provided by @jay.sf and have tried to adapt it for my situation. Can anyone let me know if I have done this properly. I am also a bit unsure what the pred code lines are doing and would really appreciate an explanation.

Thanks so much.

```
####Passive imputation for interaction terms ####### 
#Recode sex as binary in data_select to data_select2
library(dplyr)
data_select2 <- data_select
#Convert sex to binary variable
data_select2$sex <- ifelse(data_select2$sex == "Male", 0, 1) 
data_select2$sex <- as.numeric(data_select2$sex)

#Add new column for the interaction and add NA values
data_select2 <- cbind(data_select, mean_commute.sex = NA)
ini <- mice(data_select2, max=0, print = F)
#set interaction calculation for method and predictors
meth <- ini$meth
meth["mean_commute.sex"] <- "~I(mean_commute*sex)"
pred <- ini$pred
pred[c("mean_commute", "sex"), "mean_commute.sex"] <- 0 

imp <- mice(data_select2, meth = meth, pred = pred, m=5, maxit = 10, seed = 123, print = FALSE)

lm_impute2<- with(imp, lm(total_sleep ~ mean_commute+ sex + mean_commute:sex))
lm_impute_pool2 <- pool(lm_impute2)
summary(lm_impute_pool2)
```